# Appending <a> using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using Jquery Accordian in my page, Here is the HTML,

```
<div class="forms-cont">
    <h5>
        Accordian Examples</h5>
    <div class="accordian">
        <div>
            <h2 class="sch-hdr">
                Header One</h2>
            <div class="sch-cont levelOne">
                <p>
                    this is a title text - level one</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <h2 class="sch-hdr">
                Header Two</h2>
            <div class="sch-cont levelOne">
                <p>
                    This is another title text - level one
                </p>
                <div class="martop10">
                    <h3 class="subgr-hdr">
                        Staff</h3>
                    <div class="sch-cont levelTwo">
                        <p>
                            This is an inner text
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                    <h3 class="subgr-hdr">
                        Manager</h3>
                    <div class="sch-cont levelTwo">
                        <p>
                            This is an inner text
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this, i need to append an anchor tag for the accordian to work, and here is my jquery,

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 

    // Accordian Main 
    $('.accordion h2, .accordion h3').addClass('closed'); 
    $('.levelOne,.levelTwo').hide(); 
    $('.accordion h2, .accordion h3').each(function () { 
            $(this).html(function() { 
            var headertext = '<a href="#">' + $(this).html() + '</a>'; 
            return headertext; 
        }); 
    }); 

    // Level 1 Accordian 
    $(".accordion h2 a").click(function() { 
        alert('hi');
            $(this).next(".levelOne").slideToggle("slow"); 
            $(this).toggleClass("closed"); 
            return false; 
    }); 
    // Level 2 Accordian 
    $('.accordion h3 a').click(function() { 
            $(this).parent().next(".levelTwo").slideToggle("slow"); 
            $(this).parent().toggleClass("closed"); 
            return false; 
    }); 
  });
```

But i am unable to append anchor in H2 and H3. Any help?

Comment: a typo `accordian` in your html and `accordion` in your js

Comment: You aren't actually creating an accordion with this code...

Comment: @Anders: Im sorry, a slide toggler...

Comment: @bart : Yes, i find out. But no toggling happening now.

Comment: I'd recommend using jQuery UI's accordion (http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) - it's good, stable and tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: Sorry, is wrapInner() instead if wrap().

Three things:

1) You don't need  an .each(), simply:

```
$('.accordion h2, .accordion h3').wrapInner('<a href="#"></a>');
```

2) There is a typo in your html:

```
<div class="accordian">  <-- accordion?
```

3) A "parent()" is missing on the "h2 a" click event:

```
$(".accordion h2 a").click(function() { 
        $(this).next(".levelOne").slideToggle("slow"); <-- actual

$(".accordion h2 a").click(function() { 
        $(this).parent().next(".levelOne").slideToggle("slow"); <-- with parent()
```

And then it will work :)

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fy2uM/2

Answer (score 2):

In this part of your code, `this` refers to the function itself instead of the object:

```
$('.accordion h2, .accordion h3').each(function () { 
        $(this).html(function() { 
        var headertext = '<a href="#">' + $(this).html() + '</a>';   // <-- HERE
        return headertext; 
    }); 
});
```

se this instead:

```
$('.accordion h2, .accordion h3').each(function () { 
        var that = this;
        $(this).html(function() { 
        var headertext = '<a href="#">' + $(that).html() + '</a>'; 
        return headertext; 
    }); 
});
```

Here's a [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hRgv7/) demonstrating it

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you spelt accordion wrong:

change it to:

```
$('.accordian h2, .accordian h3').each(function () { 
            $(this).html(function() { 
            var headertext = '<a href="#">' + $(this).html() + '</a>'; 
            return headertext; 
        }); 
    });
```

See js fiddle here [http://jsfiddle.net/HukJE/4](http://jsfiddle.net/HukJE/4/)

Comment: I don't see the alerts coming up... fiddle seems not to work, and if you change `accordion` to `accordian` I think you should rename ALL of them

Comment: I only got the anchor tags to work, as that seemed to be the main question Try now: http://jsfiddle.net/HukJE/3/

Comment: @bart: Ya, that is what i am facing now. I need to toggle this. The second header contains two inner toggler. Please help.

Comment: @crafty: No need to confuse. I want the main toggler to work. I will take care about the inner togglers.

Comment: Just updated to get the closed class to toggle.. your css is not going to work though as it's refering to the c drive. http://jsfiddle.net/HukJE/4/